# git log - display only the first x characters of commit's message

Tags: git, git-log

I want to display only a limited number of characters (say the first 100 characters) of the commit message in `git log`

Currently, I used `git log --oneline` but this displays the first line of the message. This can be a very long line if there is no new-line-characters between lines in the message. This makes my git log ugly and not easily readable.

How can I do this?

If this is not possible to display a limited number of characters, can I display the real first line of the message, I mean if there is no break between it and the second line in the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display only a limited number of characters (say the first 100 characters) of the commit message in git log

See [placeholders](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) available for `--format`. You're interested in `%<(100)` — it cuts long lines to the given number of characters; unfortunately it pads short lines at the right to the given number of characters but that's the best you can find. So you need

```
git log --format='%h %<(100)%s'
```

> can I display the real first line of the message, I mean if there is no break between it and the second line in the message?

No, `%s` placeholder takes not the first line but the first paragraph separated by two newlines. Next time please use the best practice on how to write a good commit message:

https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#separate

You can go with more complex processing using `%B` and cutting the first line from it. Something like this:

```
git rev-parse master |
    while read sha1; do
        first_line=$(git --no-pager show -s --format='%B' | head -1)
        echo "$sha1 $first_line"
    done
```

Answer (score 2):

Using git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132) on macOS Monterey Version 12.2.1, I found that in order to actually cut to the given number of characters I had to explicitly ask it to truncate output.

Like so:

```
git log --format='%h %<(100,trunc)%s'
```

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emltltNgttruncltruncmtruncem

> ***`%<(<N>[,trunc|ltrunc|mtrunc])`***
>
> make the next placeholder take at least N columns, padding spaces on the right if necessary. Optionally truncate at the beginning (ltrunc), the middle (mtrunc) or the end (trunc) if the output is longer than N columns. Note that truncating only works correctly with N >= 2.

PS: I'd make this a comment or an edit for the existing answer, but I don't have enough rep for commenting and it says the edit queue is full. Anyways, wanted to add to what phd said.